# Importing OpenStreetMap polygons to QGis with relation attributes

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap

I'am trying to import large OSM data to QGis, namely all buildings polygons in Czech Republic. 
Finally, I imported polygons using PostGIS layer, because everything else had strong issues. See my previous question: [Importing large OSM data to QGis failed (using QuickOSM, SpatialLite layer or add vector layer)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254282/importing-large-osm-data-to-qgis-failed-using-quickosm-spatiallite-layer-or-ad).

Now, I have another problem: some attributes (tags) are missing - **probably** the attributes, that are placed in relations.

Is there method, how to apply OSM relation tags to it's sub polygons and import them to QGis?

Example: this building (relation): [openstreetmap.org/relation/3679169](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3679169) has interesting tag "building:levels" but PostGIS layer in QGis contains only  polygon without it.

Comment: Did you try to add the requested tags to your `default.style` file **before** starting the osm2pgsql import?

Comment: No I didn't. But it looks like solution! I didn't have this idea, because ".style" file extension looked like something graphic-related (green color for vegetation, etc...). I'am rigid programmer :-). I will try this and place answer... Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As AndreJ said in question comments above, I added tags to "default.style" file and it did the job. Thank You again!